# Quantify consistency of difference from the mean

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

What is the normal method of characterizing the consistency of the difference from the mean?

For example, imagine we have three vectors:

3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1
2, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4

The second series differs by a constant amount from the first series.

The difference of the third series averages to be zero, but each difference of each value is different, whereas the difference between series two and series one is the same. In other words, if we list the difference between 1 and 2 and 1 vs 3:

2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2  <-- difference between 1 and 2
1, -1, -1, 1, -2, 1, 1, 2, 1, -1  <-- difference between 1 and 3

How is this characterized?

Answer (score -1):

hello fellow history stackexchange reader . I have followed your comments for some time. Now with respect to your question , you could take each of your computed differences and analyze/characterize them. The first would clearly be a constant while the second would not be characterized as a constant thus an identifiable difference.